# EntityFramework AspNet Core migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migrations

Boa noite, me deparei com um problema para atualizar o DB de uma aplicação AspNet Core. Havia criado o banco, porém acabei deletando, agora, ao tentar criar novamente usando os seguintes comandos:

```
dotnet ef migrations Initial 
dotnet ef database update
```

Ao executar o primeiro comando recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
D:\PROGRAMACAO\FONTES\ASPNET\LIVRO\FilmeMvc\src\FilmeMvc>dotnet ef migrations add InitialProject FilmeMvc (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation. Done. To undo this action, use 'dotnet ef migrations remove'
```

Removi toda a aplicação, refiz a mesma novamente, entretando ao adicionar o primeiro comando no 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2015' recebo a mensagem citada. Como poderia resolver essa questão.

Comment: Você tem que remover (deletar) e recompilar (ReBuild) o projeto.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, obrigado pela dica, estava deletando, mas não estava recompilando o projeto, fiz o que me orientou e ocorreu tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Exclua os dados da tabela MigrationHistory ou execute dotnet ef migrations remove como sugere a mensagem.

Comment: Boa Noite. Já executei o comando mencionado, entretanto, ao recriar, retorna a mesma mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolução: Após a exclusão, efetuado Rebuild, resolveu o que estava ocorrendo.